# Execute JavaScript in tab persisting across page navigation

Tags: javascript, scope, persistence

I'm trying to figure out how to automate click events in order to automate  advancing through a series of queues of items. Here are the specifics:

- There are 1 or more queues of items (user-determined in this script)
- Each queue has a variable number of items
- The URL of the queue page is static
- Each queue is started by clicking a button on the queue page
- The `querySelector` of the button on the queue page is static and known
- Clicking the button on the queue page loads the page of the first item in the queue
- Each item page is at a different URL (same-origin as the queue begin URL)
- Clicking a button on the item page loads the page of the next item
- The `querySelector` of the button on the item page is static and known
- On the page of the last item in the queue, clicking the button loads the queue page

Here's a visual diagram of the flow:
[image]

After writing the script to do this task, I realized that I can't persist the running script across page navigation (at least I don't think so). I even looked at making a Chrome extension and using [content scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts), but I don't think that will persist the js across page navigation.

How can I achieve my goal?

Comment: Save information in `sessionStorage` (or `localStorage` if it needs to persist across window closes/opens as well)

Comment: What if it were cross-origin? @CertainPerformance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) or [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) can help you store simple data across page transitions.

Another option is to look into a framework or a library that can give you javascript routing. Routing will allow your javascript to persist across page loads and will allow you to pass more complicated data around your application without losing state.